# Problem accesing email property with help of Expression Language/JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, el

In my Servlet:

```
person.setEmail(eMail);
request.getSession().setAttribute("person", person);

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/JSPAddress");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

My Bean Class:

```
private String eMail;

public Person(String eMail) {
    setEmail(eMail);
}

public String getEmail() {
    return eMail;
}
public void setEmail(String Email) {
    this.eMail = Email;
}
```

In my JSPAddress:

```
<input type="text" size="45" name="email" value='<c:out value="${person.eMail}" />' >
```

What I want:

- An email value in textfield, which is set in a Servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) accesses properties by getters, not directly by the field. If your setter is named `setEmail()` then your getter is likely named `getEmail()`, so the property name is really `email`, not `eMail`.

Thus, this should do

```
${person.email}
```

Comment: That was not necessary. Did you fix the JSP code as per my answer?

Comment: Yeah. Its working. Can you explain, where was I going wroung?

Comment: You was trying to access it by the field name instead of the getter name. As I answered, EL accesses properties by getters (those methods starting with `get`), not by fields.